# How to load data from firebase with angularfire when page loads?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm a newbie in angularfire. I've bootstrapped a simple application which stores data in firebase and shows that data in same page. This application has two views. However I must refresh the page in order to load the records and display them in page. 
I have a Controller and a Service. Controller calls the Service which communicates with firebase.
It's something like this below:

```
FooController(dependencies injections){
    $scope.var  = FooService.loadDataFromFirebase();
}

FooService(//dependencies injetions ){
  this.loadDataFromFirebase = function(){
      $scope.bar = //logic to load data from firebase
   }
}
```

As I said, it only displays the data loaded from firebase after a page refresh. I`d like to see the records as soon as page loads.

Comment: Firebase has a pretty decent guide for AngularFire that covers these topics better than we can in a Q&A format. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/index.html If you think that is not the problem, please provide a minimal **complete** reproduction of the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You'll specifically want to see how your current code differs from this: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html#section-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've made a mistake. Before FooService sets $scope.bar with records from firebase there was a $scope.bar init inside controller. I've removed it and everything worked as expected.